Unity - OVR Lipsync Stops Working When Playing Animation on 3D Model
I have a 3d model with OVR Lipsync and an idle animation.
The OVR Lipsync programmatically changes blendshape weights based on an audio source, and it seems to only work while the model is not animated. Any idea why adding the idle animation causes it to stop working?
